# yii:how to run a function before run submitbutton

Tags: php, yii

i need run a function before run submit button in yii 1.1.X

my function is `getcode()` in this form

this is my code in **_form.php**

i want set value of ( group textfiled ) from this function

```
<?php
/* @var $this TextController */
/* @var $model Text */
/* @var $form CActiveForm */

?>

<div class="form">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'text-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>TRUE,
     'focus'=>array($model,'group'),
  //   'clientOptions'=>array(
     //           'validateOnChange'=>true,  // the default. validate when input changes
     //           'validateOnType'=>'true',    // validate with EVERY keystroke, hooray!
      //          'validationDelay'=>10,     // not related to this post--but cool!
      //                                // default delay is 200 ms
    //    ),
)); ?>

    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'subject'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'subject',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>80)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'subject'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'matn'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'matn',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>255)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'matn'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'group'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'group',array('value'=>$groupNumber , 'size'=>20,'maxlength'=>20)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'group'); ?>

    </div>
<?php $userX=yii::app()->session['idX']; ?>

    <div class="row">
        <?php // echo $form->labelEx($model,'user_id'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'user_id',array ('value'=>$userX,'type'=>"hidden")); ?>
        <?php // echo $form->error($model,'user_id'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Privacy'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'Privacy',  array('1'=>'Public','2'=>'Only me')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'Privacy'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row buttons">

        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save' ); ?>
    </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div><!-- form -->

<?php
function getcode()
{
    $groupNumber =Text::model()->maxIdNote();
}
```

how to run this function before saving form.

this is my text model

```
<?php

/**
 * This is the model class for table "text".
 *
 * The followings are the available columns in table 'text':
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $subject
 * @property string $matn
 * @property string $group
 * @property integer $user_id
 * @property integer $Privacy
 *
 * The followings are the available model relations:
 * @property Users $user
 */
class Text extends CActiveRecord
{

    public $newId=0 ;
    /**
     * @return string the associated database table name
     */
    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'text';
    }

    /**
     * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.
        return array(
            array('subject, user_id, Privacy ,group', 'required'),
            array('user_id, Privacy', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
            array('subject', 'length', 'max'=>80),
            array('matn', 'length', 'max'=>255),
            array('group', 'length', 'max'=>20 , 'min'=>2),
                   array('group', 'comp_group'),

            // The following rule is used by search().
            // @todo Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            array('id, subject, matn, group, user_id, Privacy', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
        );
    }

            public function getidX()

      {

            $user= Yii::app()->db->createCommand();
   //     SELECT users.username from users INNER JOIN text  on text.user_id=users.id
         //   SELECT users.username FROM users,  text  WHERE users.id=text.user_id;
     $user = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->select('users.id')
    ->from('users')
    ->where('users.id=:username' , array(':username'=>1))
//    ->where('id=:id', array(':id'=>$id))
    ->queryRow();
Yii::app()->session['idX']=$user;
    return $user;
      }






    /**
     * @return array relational rules.
     */
    public function relations()
    {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
            'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Users', 'user_id'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'id' => 'ID',
            'subject' => 'Subject',
            'matn' => 'Matn',
            'group' => 'Group',
            'user_id' => 'User',
            'Privacy' => 'Privacy',
        );
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
     *
     * Typical usecase:
     * - Initialize the model fields with values from filter form.
     * - Execute this method to get CActiveDataProvider instance which will filter
     * models according to data in model fields.
     * - Pass data provider to CGridView, CListView or any similar widget.
     *
     * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models
     * based on the search/filter conditions.
     */
    public function search()
    {
        // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
        $criteria->compare('subject',$this->subject,true);
        $criteria->compare('matn',$this->matn,true);
        $criteria->compare('group',$this->group,true);
        $criteria->compare('user_id',$this->user_id);
        $criteria->compare('Privacy',$this->Privacy);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
     * Please note that you should have this exact method in all your CActiveRecord descendants!
     * @param string $className active record class name.
     * @return Text the static model class
     */
    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

       public function comp_group($attributes , $params)
         {

            $sqlname='SHOW COLUMNS FROM `group`';
            $gpnamet = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sqlname);
            $gpall =$gpnamet->queryAll();
            $sqlnumber="SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE  table_name = 'group' ";
            $sqlnumberquery= Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sqlnumber);
            $sqlnumberall=$sqlnumberquery->queryAll();
            $numberColumns=( $sqlnumberall[0]['COUNT(*)']);

            for ($t=1 ; $t<$numberColumns ;$t++)
                {
                    $columnsArray[]=($gpall[$t]['Field']);

                }

    $test_status=FALSE;
    $numberint=0;

         $masterCommand = Yii::app()->db->createCommand();
                  $gname=$this->group;
              foreach ($columnsArray as $u)
              {
                   //  اگه گروه وارد شده موجود بود
                if ($this->group == $u )
                    {
                 $this->clearErrors('group');
             //    $this->addError('group' ," $gname already registered");
                 $masterCommand->reset();
                 $masterCommand->insert('group',
                          array
                                  (
                                       $this->group=>'1',
                                   ));
                  $masterCommand->reset();
                  $this->newId=$masterCommand->select('max(id)')->from('group')->queryAll();
                  $this->newId=$this->newId[0]['max(id)'];
                  $test_status=TRUE;

                  break;

                   }

          }
           // اگه گروه وارد شده موجود نبود و نیاز داشت به ستون ها اضافه شود
         foreach ($columnsArray as $u)   
         {
            if($test_status==FALSE && $this->group != $u)
                    {

                        $this->clearErrors('group');
                   //      $this->addError('group' ," $gname not registered");



                           if($numberint==0)
                           {
                            $masterCommand->reset();
                          $masterCommand->addColumn('group' , $gname , 'int(1)'); 
                         $masterCommand->reset();
                          $masterCommand->insert('group', array(
                                          $this->group=>'1',
                               ));
                            $masterCommand->reset();
                             $this->newId = $masterCommand->select('max(id)')->from('group')->queryAll();
                             $this->newId= $this->newId[0]['max(id)'];

                              $numberint++;

                               }
                          }
                   }
             }







      public function  maxIdNote()
      {
         return $this->newId;
      }
}
```

Comment: You want the `getcode()` function to be executed/run when the form/page is loaded, so that the `group` text-field is loaded with `$groupNumber` value?

Comment: If yes, then before `<div class="form">` line of code, just write `$groupNumber = Text::model()->maxIdNote();`, no need of `getcode` function.

Comment: no i want getcode() is run when client click on submit(create)

Comment: Because Text::model()->maxIdNote() is in The Changing

Comment: If `getcode` is to be executed on click then it should be a `javascript` code. Eg: onclick of the submibutton, make an ajax call, on success - get the value and display in the textbox. Then do the form submit.

Comment: thanks! can I run a php function in onclick?

Comment: PHP is always executed before javascript and so the Ajax exists. I have added an answer wherein, onclick of the submit button, the form submit is prevented, an Ajax call is made to the ACTION_NAME, the action returns the required `maxIdNote()` value, the returned value is set to the Textbox and the form submit is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (please replace the required values, especially ACTION_NAME) -

Change in view file -

```
<?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save' ); ?>
```

to

```
<?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save', array('id' => 'text_form_submit') ); ?>
```

Write this at the end of the view file -

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#text_form_submit').click(function(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                url: '<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl("text/ACTION_NAME"); ?>',
                success:function(data){
                    if(data !==  null) {
                        $('#Text_group').val(data);
                        $('#text-form').submit();
                    }
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert("Error occured!!!.");
                },
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

In TextController -

Create a new action (same as what is mentioned in replacement to `ACTION_NAME`) -

```
public function actionACTION_NAME() {
    $groupNumber = Text::model()->maxIdNote();
    echo json_encode($groupNumber);
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks

.
However, if the error occurs
Even when I manually set value in $ groupNumber = Text :: model () -> maxIdNote ();

Comment: You mean the ajax call returns the value or not?

Comment: Please show us your controller action code and ajax script from view file.

Comment: i sent
I do not understand the whole Ajax!

Comment: In controller file - change `public function actionACTION_NAME()` to `public function actionMaxnoteid()`. In view file - change `url: '<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl("text/ACTION_NAME"); ?>',` to `url: '<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl("text/maxnoteid"); ?>',`

Comment: Again, not true! 
The problem is not the name

Comment: I've also added models


ajax of the model is correct
At the camp-group ()
Does the work properly


If that time was a very well could be a result Return to form

Comment: I have given you the answer only after trying it in my demo project. Please check in the javascript console of the browser as what is been returned in the ajax call. Check it only after changing the name as mentioned in my last comment.

Comment: in the console of my browser have this index.php/text/maxnoteid 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: In controller - change `'actions'=>array('create','update'),` to `'actions'=>array('create','update', 'maxnoteid'),`

Answer (score 0):

this is new my code

_form.php

```
<div class="form">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'text-form',

    // See class documentation of CActiveForm for details on this.
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>TRUE,
   // 'action'=>$this->createUrl('TextController/performAjaxValidation'),
     'focus'=>array($model,'group'),
  //   'clientOptions'=>array(
     //           'validateOnChange'=>true,  // the default. validate when input changes
     //           'validateOnType'=>'true',    // validate with EVERY keystroke, hooray!
      //          'validationDelay'=>10,     // not related to this post--but cool!
      //                                // default delay is 200 ms
    //    ),
)); ?>

    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'subject'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'subject',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>80)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'subject'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'matn'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'matn',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>255)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'matn'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'group'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'group',array('size'=>20,'maxlength'=>20,'value'=>$test)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'group'); ?>
    </div>
<?php $userX=yii::app()->session['idX']; ?>

    <div class="row">
        <?php // echo $form->labelEx($model,'user_id'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'user_id',array ('value'=>$userX,'type'=>"hidden")); ?>
        <?php // echo $form->error($model,'user_id'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Privacy'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'Privacy',  array('1'=>'Public','2'=>'Only me')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'Privacy'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row buttons">
      <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save', array('id' => 'text_form_submit') ); ?>

    </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div><!-- form -->

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#text_form_submit').click(function(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                url: '<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl("text/ACTION_NAME"); ?>',
                success:function(data){
                //    if(data !==  null)
                    {
                   //     $('#Text_group').val(data);
                    //    $('#text-form').submit();
                         alert("not Error occured!!!.");
                    }
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert("Error occured!!!.");
                },
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

this is my textController

```
<?php

class TextController extends Controller
{


    /**
     * @var string the default layout for the views. Defaults to '//layouts/column2', meaning
     * using two-column layout. See 'protected/views/layouts/column2.php'.
     */
    public $layout='//layouts/column2';

    /**
     * @return array action filters
     */
    public function filters()
    {

        return array(
            'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
            'postOnly + delete', // we only allow deletion via POST request
        );
    }

    /**
     * Specifies the access control rules.
     * This method is used by the 'accessControl' filter.
     * @return array access control rules
     */
    public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
                'actions'=>array('index','view'),
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
                'actions'=>array('create','update'),
                'users'=>array('@'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
                'actions'=>array('admin','delete'),
                'users'=>array('admin'),
            ),
            array('deny',  // deny all users
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Displays a particular model.
     * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be displayed
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
              $model=$this->loadModel($id);

    //check user_id
    if ($model->user_id !== Yii::app()->user->id)
    {
        echo "YOU SHALL NOT PASS !";
        Yii::app()->end();
    }

        $this->render('view',array(
            'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new Text;

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
         $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Text']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Text'];
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        $this->render('create',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Updates a particular model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be updated
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
          $model=$this->loadModel($id);

    //check user_id
    if ($model->user_id !== Yii::app()->user->id)
    {
        echo "YOU SHALL NOT PASS !";
        Yii::app()->end();
    }

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['Text']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Text'];
        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
    }

    $this->render('update',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
    }

    /**
     * Deletes a particular model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'admin' page.
     * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be deleted
     */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->loadModel($id)->delete();

        // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
        if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
            $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
    }

    /**
     * Lists all models.
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
          // group model
           //   $dataProvidergroup=new CActiveDataProvider('group',array(
        //    'criteria' => array(
           // 'condition' => 'name=:user_id',
          //  'params' => array(':user_id' => Yii::app()->User->id),)
                //  ));



            //note of user
            $dataProviderself=new CActiveDataProvider('Text',array(
            'criteria' => array(
            'condition' => 'user_id=:user_id',
            'params' => array(':user_id' => Yii::app()->User->id),)));


            // public notes of users
            $dataProviderpublic = new CActiveDataProvider('Text',array(
            'criteria' => array(
            'condition' => 'privacy=:privacy',
            'params' => array(':privacy' => 1),)));



            $this->render('index',array(
        'dataProviderpublic'=>$dataProviderpublic ,
        'dataProviderself'=>$dataProviderself ,

    ));




//      $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Text');
//      $this->render('index',array(
//          'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
//      ));
    }

    /**
     * Manages all models.
     */
    public function actionAdmin()
    {
        $model=new Text('search');
        $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
        if(isset($_GET['Text']))
            $model->attributes=$_GET['Text'];

        $this->render('admin',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Returns the data model based on the primary key given in the GET variable.
     * If the data model is not found, an HTTP exception will be raised.
     * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be loaded
     * @return Text the loaded model
     * @throws CHttpException
     */
       public $s=0;
    public function loadModel($id)
    {
        $model=Text::model()->findByPk($id);
        if($model===null)
            throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');
        return $model;
    }

    /**
     * Performs the AJAX validation.
     * @param Text $model the model to be validated
     */
    protected function performAjaxValidation($model)
    {

          if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='text-form')
        {
            echo CActiveForm::validate($model);

            Yii::app()->end();
        }
    }

      public function actionACTION_NAME()
              {
              $groupNumber = 26;
                      //Text::model()->maxIdNote();
              echo json_encode($groupNumber);
              exit();
}
}
```