# Yii: run a function when a submitButton is pressed

Tags: php, yii

I'm very new to Yii, and trying to understand an existing web app, so please bear with me.

I've been having issues with a certain function, that seems to fail retaining data whenever `actionView` is called[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36605411/yii-id-getting-overwritten-on-load), but I thought perhaps I was going about this problem all wrong.

Instead, I thought perhaps the button could directly run the function from the controller, instead of... whatever it was doing prior.

I looked at a sample [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/32943-action-call-from-button/) that had this:

```
<?php echo CHtml::submitButton('CSV Report', array('submit'=>'getReport')); ?>
```

Where `getReport` is the function in my controller (actionGetReport).

Unfortunately, it's not working. Here's the code of my `_commentform.php`:

```
<?php $post = $forum; ?>
<?php $comment = $model; ?>
<div id="comment_form<?=$post->id?>" class="other-member-comment-box">

<?php 
 $user=Persons::model()->findByAttributes(array('party_id'=>Yii::app()->user->id)); 
 $country=Lookup_codes::model()->findByAttributes(array('id'=>$user->country)); 
 $location = empty($country) ? '' : 'from '.$country->name;
?>
 <div class="user-profilepic">
    <a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('persons/view/id/'.$user->showViewLinkId())?>"><img src="<?php 
        if(!empty($user->image) AND file_exists( Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/images/profile_picture/'.$user->party_id . $user->image)){
            echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/profile_picture/'.$user->party_id . $user->image;
        } else echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/profile_picture/NA.jpg';
     ?>"></a>
 </div>
<div class="form">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'comment-form',
    'action'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('forum/view/id/'.$forum->id),
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
)); ?>

    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>
    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->hiddenField($model,'node_type_id',array('value'=>'7')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'node_type'); ?>
    </div>
        <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->hiddenField($model,'content_id',array('value'=>$forum->id)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'content_id'); ?>
    </div>
        <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->hiddenField($model,'category',array('value'=>$forum->category)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'category'); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->textArea($model,'content',array('rows'=>6, 'cols'=>90),array('id'=>'sample')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'content'); ?>
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $view; ?>" id="view" name="view"/>
    <div class="row buttons">
    <?php
    if ($view == 'view'){
        if ($model->isNewRecord) {
            echo CHtml::submitButton('Reply', array('id'=>'comment'.$comment->id));
        } else {
            echo CHtml::button('Save', array('submit'=>'updatecomment'));
        }
    }?>
    </div>
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
</div><!-- form -->
</div>
```

And here's the `UpdateComment` function from my controller:

```
public function actionUpdateComment()
{
    Yii::log(CVarDumper::dumpAsString("ForumController: Update COMMENT!"));
    Yii::log(CVarDumper::dumpAsString($_POST['Comment']));
    exit();
}
```

I'm not exactly sure what I'll get by the `$_POST['Comment']`, but if the code worked, I'd very least expect it to log out the `"ForumController: Update COMMENT!"`. It doesn't.

I tried changing the `submitButton` to `button`, but that just kills the button function entirely.

Next, I tried [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24219194/yiihow-to-run-a-function-before-run-submitbutton).

So I changed the `submitButton` code to this:

```
echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Reply' : 'Save',array('id'=>'comment'.$comment->id));
```

And added this to the end:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#text_form_submit').click(function(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({ type: 'POST', dataType: 'JSON',
                url: '<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl("forum/UpdateComment"); ?>',
                success:function(data){
                    if(data !==  null) {
                        $('#Text_group').val(data);
                        $('#text-form').submit();
                    }
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert("Error occured!!!.");
                },
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Not exactly sure what the code does, other than call a function as well, but as well, it doesn't work (I also changed POST from GET and back).

Any suggestions? I feel like `CActiveForm` is to blame here, but even modifying that causes the site to fail in loading pages.

Answer (score 0):

You have a long question and could be you should split your question in more question with simple question each ..

A firts answer  the submit button don't contain the target function see this doc

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#submitButton-detail

the target function (php controller/action) is defined in form .. this is from html .. is the form definition that define the target for the submitted data ..

if you want execute the actionGetReport  you should define the target in form action

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
   'id'=>'comment-form',
   'action'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('yourController/actionGetReport'),
   'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
 )); ?>
```

Comment: Yes, I've been playing around with createUrl. But what if I need two URL's? One for button Reply and another for button Save, as with my If Else statement in the code. How do I do that?

Comment: No the target is one only .. is the actionCreate or the actionUpdate that invoke different form (header) .. in the related view if the action is update then is showed the button reply otherwise if the action is create is showed the button save ..

Comment: I suggest you of start with a sample begineer project and evaluate this simple code then after this trial  you can evaluate more complex code

Comment: No way to change the URL depending on the button? I'm afraid the URL specified in createURL defaults to a page that erases the data stored when submitButton is clicked.

Comment: Is not what yii  suggest .. for this you can change the action property by jquery..

Comment: Any samples for the Jquery? How would that work with the url set to /forum/view/id? For the Save function to work, that needs to be /forum/updatecomment/id or something like that.

Comment: No ... i repeat myself is not the way suggest by Yii

Comment: So, are you saying, this workaround I thought off is not possible?

Comment: No. is possibile..but not adapt to yii ... otherwise  the way prposed by yii is very simple  .. you shoulld only approach this problem by the begin .. try use the sample project for beginner  and could see how  the actionCreate and actionUpdate are proposed by yii and then you can find the correct way for manage you problem ..

Comment: I'll see what I can do, thanks. I'm afraid I'm only allowed to make minor changes to the code proper - most of these are already in place, and to start over would consume the deadline - which is why I was looking for out-of-the-box solutions.